# Uncaught Exception in jQuery Function

Tags: php, jquery, supersized

The below code causes:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Any ideas how to resolve this issue? My goal is to use supersize with directory image discovery instead of the static HTML entries that it is written with. I found an article (http://www.zachmelo.com/customizing-supersize-jquery/) that speaks of this very thing, but the code throws the error at slides: `[<`

```
        jQuery(function($){

            $.supersized({

                // Functionality
                slide_interval          :   3000,       // Length between transitions
                transition              :   1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   700,        // Speed of transition

                // Components                           
                slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
            slides  :[<?php
                    $directory = "/img/"; 
                    $directory_thumbs = "/img/thumbs/"; 
                    $images = glob($directory . "*.png"); 
                    $images_thumb = glob($directory_thumbs . "*.png"); 
                    $images_final = array_combine($images,$images_thumb); 
                    foreach($images_final as $image = $key) 
                    {
                        $name= $image; 
                        $name-chop= trim($name, $directory); 
                        $name-chop= trim($name-chop, ".png"); 
                        $name-chop= str_replace('_',' ', $name-chop); 
                        echo "{image : ' $image ', title : ' $name-chop ' , thumb : '$key' },";
                    }?>]
        });
```

Comment: Would you think it is appropriate for us to know what `slides[ >>> ... <<<]` contains as raw data? Anyways, I think its better to just do `echo json_encode($images_final)` instead of manually building your json data. Meaning, pre build your array in php. Also, there is a syntax error.

Comment: `foreach($images_final as $image => $key)` But... flip `$image` and `$key` around.

Comment: The raw data are Image files maybe? I will try your suggestion. Thanks.